# Rails app not accessible through subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I have deployed a Rails 4 app onto a digitalocean server.
Stack is Nginx-Unicorn-Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a domain at say abc.com ( and this domain has another website hosted elsewhere )
I created a subdomain called support.abc.com, and pointed it to the digitalocean server.

When i head to support.abc.com, I get this result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<title>support.abc.com</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
<frame src="http://<ip address of droplet>" frameborder="0" />
<frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 03 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

When I access the app through the IP address of droplet, the app works fine.
Only when I head to support.abc.com I get the above page, which is basically a blank page.

How do i make it work?

Comment: Did you check their guide on this? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-test-dns-subdomains-with-digitalocean-s-dns-panel

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your DNS records. Have you set up an A record or CNAME pointing the subdomain to that IP address? Have you given it enough time for the record to propagate?

Comment: @andrewsomething Yes i have set up a record. Plus, when I change unicorn and nginx settings to a different folder with just an HTML page, that page shows without any issue.

Comment: @Rudolf yeah i've setup up those settings as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
The problem wasn't with Rails.
The client had "forwarded" the subdomain to the IP instead of adding an A record.